# instanceof with arrays Java

Tags: java, instanceof

I am working with a class called Employee and two subclasses called SalariedEmployee and HourlyEmployee. In this part of my code, I am trying to test if an Employee in an array is either a SalariedEmployee or an HourlyEmployee. However, it is only printing the attributes from the original Employee class, not from the subclasses.

```
case 2: {
     for(int index = 0; index < employees.length; index++ ) {
          System.out.println( employees[index] + "\n" );
          if(employees[index] instanceof SalariedEmployee) {
              SalariedEmployee aSalariedEmployee = (SalariedEmployee) employees[index];
              System.out.println( aSalariedEmployee.toString() );
          }
          else if(employees[index] instanceof HourlyEmployee) {
               HourlyEmployee anHourlyEmployee = (HourlyEmployee) employees[index];
               System.out.println( anHourlyEmployee.toString() );
          }
          else {
               System.out.println( " " );
          }
      }
      System.out.println( " " );
      break;
 }
```

Here is the data-collection part of my code: (EDIT: updated = to == in while loop)

```
int typeEmployee;
boolean loop = true;
OUTER:
while (loop == true) {
     System.out.print( "Enter 1 if the Employee is Salaried, 2 if Hourly: " );
     typeEmployee = info.nextInt();
         switch (typeEmployee) {
            case 1:
                 System.out.print( "Enter the Employee's Salary (with no commas): " );
                 float annSalary = info.nextFloat();
                 SalariedEmployee aSalariedEmployee = new SalariedEmployee(annSalary);
                 aSalariedEmployee.setAnnualSalary(annSalary);
                 break OUTER;
            case 2:
                 System.out.print( "Enter the Employee's Hourly Pay Rate: " );
                 float hPRate = info.nextFloat();
                 System.out.print( "Enter the number of Hours Worked in a week: " );
                 float hWorked = info.nextFloat();
                 HourlyEmployee anHourlyEmployee = new HourlyEmployee(hPRate, hWorked);
                 anHourlyEmployee.setHourlyPayRate(hPRate);
                 anHourlyEmployee.setHoursWorked(hWorked);
                 break OUTER;
            default:
                 System.out.println( "Invalid Option." );
                 break;
       }
 }
```

I feel like what I'm missing here is I need to somehow associate the typeEmployee with the object itself.  Does anyone know how I can do this?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Shouldn't `while (loop = true)` be `while (loop)` (without possibly harmful assignment) or `for(;;)` (simple infinite loop)?

Comment: Yes, that was a careless error on my part but it still does not answer the bigger question.

Comment: You don't need to check `instanceof SalariedEmployee` etc. `employees[index].toString()` and `((SalariedEmployee) employees[index]).toString()` invoke exactly the same method.

Comment: @AndyTurner What would you recommend I do in place of this?

Answer (score 2):

> it is only printing the attributes from the original Employee class,
>   not from the subclasses.

You need to override `toString()` in the sub-classes to include new attributes.

Comment: And if that is all you needed, you don't need to do the `instanceof` and cast at all. If the employee instances know how to print themselves, the calling method does not need to discriminate. The beauty of polymorphism.

Comment: @Thilo I have already added the Override before the toString method in the subclasses, it still does not work.

Comment: Please include the implementations of all `toString` methods in the question.